# How to display the string content of this array all at once using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

I am using this for form validation. I call this function when there is an error and i send it a string as a parameter.

```
var errList = new Array();
    function aerrorList(error){
        errList.push(error);
        for (var i=0; i < errList.length; i++){
            alert(errList[i]);
        }
    }
```

here is one of the validation checks:

```
function lNameValidate() {
        var lName = document.getElementById("lastname");
        if (lName.value.length < 20 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(lName.value)){
            stNumValidate();
        } else {
            lName.style.border = "red";
            errorList("Invalid lName Format");
            stNumValidate();
        }
    }
```

The current array (using alert) displays the error in a number of popup boxes with only 1 error string each. i want it to display 1 alert which would show all the errors in a list similar to outputting it in a bullet point way.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: could you tell me how?

Comment: Have you tried putting alert out of the loop and store the values got from looping in a temporary container similar to this?
var temp = "";
for (var i=0; i < errList.length; i++){
temp += errList[i];
}
alert(temp); Or you can create a custom alert to display the result into a bullet. Alerts can't display html

Answer (score 2):

You can append all the errors to one `var` and then display it:

`function aerrorList(error){
        errList.push(error);
        var errors = "";
        for (var i=0; i < errList.length; i++){
            errors += errList[i] + "\n";
        }
        alert(errors);
    }`

Comment: Or just `alert(errList.join('\n'))`.

Comment: I will not alert once. Cuz everytime aerrorList() will be called it will alert again with old errors. Think about validation functions that each of them calls aerrorList(). I think must be function pushError(error){errList.push(error);}  and then showErrors(){alert(errList.join("\n"));}

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join` method on an array, Here's an example:

`errors=['error1','error2','error3']`

Here, a is an array of list of your errors, now you can glue them together using whatever you want like this:

`error_string=error.join("\n*")`

Finally you can make an alert:

`alert(error_string)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
    var Errors = {
      messages: [],
      push: function(message) {
          this.messages.push(message);
      },
      alert: function() {
          alert(this.messages.join("\n"));
      },
      showInElement: function(element) {
          element.innerHTML = this.messages.join('<br/>');
      },
      clear: function() {
          this.messages = [];
      }
    }

    var age = 1;
    if(age < 18) {
      Errors.push("Come back when You 18+");
    }

    var name = "Jack";
    if(name != "John") {
      Errors.push("You're not John!");
    }

    Errors.alert();

    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    Errors.showInElement(element);

    Errors.clear();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using this:

```
    var errList = new Array();
    function errorList(error){
        errList.push(error);
    }

    function showErrors() {
        alert(errList.join("\n"));
    }
```

where i just call showErrors on the very last validation check if the errList length is > 1 as such:

```
function emailRestrict() {
        var eVal = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var atPos = eVal.indexOf("@");
        var dotPos = eVal.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atPos < 1 || dotPos < atPos || dotPos >= eVal.length) {
            errorList("not valid email");
            if (errList.length > 1){
                showErrors();
            }
        return false;
        }
        else {
            if (errList.length > 1){
                showErrors();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```